# Python Discord Poll Bot Error Whilst Coding

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, syntax-error, bots

I keep getting **syntax errors** usually along the lines of:

```
require('discord.js'); 
       ^ Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax
```

I am making a **discord bot** and one feature is to **create a poll** and there are always errors with my poll code. I think it is to do with **lines 8, 14, and 15**. It might also be to do with my **parenthesis** or installing **discord.js**.
Why is this happening? Here is the poll part of my code:

```
import discord
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

npm install discord.js

client = discord.Client()

from keep_alive import keep_alive

const {Client, RichEmbed} = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();

const token = 'TOKEN'

const PREFIX = 't!'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

bot.on('message', message =>{
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch(args[0]){

    case "poll":
        const Embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x0096ff)
        .setTitle("Poll")
        .setDescription("t!poll to make a yes or no poll");

        if(largs[1]){
          message.channel.send(Embed);
          break;
        }

        let msgArgs = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        message.channel.send("**" + msgArgs + "**").then(messageReaction => {
          messageReaction.react("");
          messageReaction.react("");
          message.delete(3000).catch(console.error);
        })

    break;
  }

});
```

Comment: Are you using `discord.py` or `discord.js`?

Comment: You seem to be mixing JS and Python code.

Comment: I have changed it from npm install discord.js to pip install discord.py however now i get an invalid syntax error on the letter i

Comment: Just because you changed from npm to pip doesn't mean that javascript code can be interpreted by a python interpreter. You need to change your whole code. Most of your code has no meaning in python. Please check [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial) to find out what language elements python has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python code for simple polling:

```py
# poll command
@bot.command(description="sets up a poll")
async def poll(ctx, *, arg):
    # await ctx.send('{} Poll started by {}: '.format(ctx.message.guild.roles[0], ctx.author.mention))
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('Poll started by {}: '.format(ctx.author.mention))
    m = await ctx.send('`{}`'.format(arg))
    await m.add_reaction('')
    await m.add_reaction('')
    await m.add_reaction('')
```